# Why can users delete their questions if someone already contributed an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I [helped the user @Natsu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242363/desperately-need-help-with-a-task-for-a-test-in-magento-1-9-3?noredirect=1#comment338557_242363) to solve his employment test. I spent **half a day** on it, because there were many things that I did not knew myself. So I posted my answer and he commented that it solved his problem!

But then an hour later he deleted his question and my whole work was pointless! I answered the question not only for him, but for many other users who will have the same question in the future.

Why can users delete their questions which already have an answer, wasting the helpers time? I won't help any fresh users anymore after this, thats for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Black, I am sorry as you had felt bad for this scenario.

In more perspective, this user should not delete their question when anyone gives a useful answer over it. But As a Q&A  community member, a user can delete his/her delete their, it is his/her call. We cannot changes a user mindset :).

As this question and answer both have a valuable for the community, So at last day, I saw your post and I have Undelete question. Now it open.

Comment: Thank you very much!